# How to remove whitespace from start and end? Tokenizer(split='[.!?]')

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, whitespace, strip

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(split='[.!?]') #create a token based on sentences
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['Cleaned'].values)
X_data = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['Cleaned'].values)
X_sequ = pad_sequences(X_data)
```

I got the list of tokens whith whitespace, like blow
#let see the frist 10 of our text sequences

```
list(tokenizer.word_index)[:10]
```

**Output like this below**

```
[' rnfbdhl yis',
 ' oromoon bilisoomsiteeti jirti',
 ' namni oromummaa isaatiin mataa gadi qabtee deemu hin jiru yeroo ammaa tanatti']
```

how i can remove whitespace from start and end automatically?
please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expression using re in python. So here it goes, The caret symbol tells us the beginning of a string, the dollar is the end of string, \s+ means one or more spaces. So the regular expression means, replace every space(one or more) at the beginning or end of a string with ''(nothing). Let me know if it has worked for you.

```
import re
[re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', item) for item in list(tokenizer.word_index)]
```

With given string:

```
x = [' rnfbdhl yis', ' oromoon bilisoomsiteeti jirti', ' namni oromummaa isaatiin mataa gadi qabtee deemu hin jiru yeroo ammaa tanatti']
```

**Output**:

```
[re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', item) for item in x]
['rnfbdhl yis', 'oromoon bilisoomsiteeti jirti', 'namni oromummaa isaatiin mataa gadi qabtee deemu hin jiru yeroo ammaa tanatti']
```

Comment: @BêdâsâWâyêssâ , please check the green tick mark as answer accepted you can also upvote if you liked it , Read it here ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers